# Separate housenumber from address

Tags: php

I have to split address and housenumber for a loopup function.

It is important that this works for any kind of addresses, so I am not 100% sure how to do this the best way possible.

Addresses can look like

```
Mystreet 14a
Mystreet 4
Mystreet 4a
Wilderness and I have no housenumber
```

I guess the logic should check for a number followed by a letter or two.

Any nice ways to do this?

**TO CLARIFY: This is a lookup for Norwegian addresses where I believe the address is one or more words followed by optional number. The number may also contain a optional letter at the end (see examples above).**

Comment: Will it always look like that? "and I have no housenumber"? Also, will housenumber always begin with a number? can't it be something like a4?

Comment: Separate form fields for address and housenumber are not an option?

Comment: @Truth : I think so, yes. Housenumbers on Norway begin with a number followed by an optional letter if it's a house-complex.

Comment: @AnPel : Not possible as this is information from one system tested against another. The first system has the address as a whole.

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_numbering

Comment: Where I am from there are many more options when it comes to address formats: My Street 1, Some other Street 2, Mystreet 1-3 to name only a few. Oh, and if you are from New York you could encounter things like 2nd Street 135 and such, right? Basically I'd say there is no simple rule to split the number from the street name.

Comment: Do you always work with Norwegian addresses or can they be from anywhere in the world?  For example, in Britain, house number usually goes before the street name; moreover, in some cases house number is not really a number but a name instead (i.e. building name followed by the street name)

Comment: Just for luck, think of New York street names like "5th Avenue", so "1000 5th Avenue" is the Metropolitan Museum of Art, while "5th Avenue and 57th Street" is the address for Tiffany's jewellers

Comment: @AleksG : This is a site for ordering electricity for a company in Norway, so that is no problem.

Comment: I see. one more point: how are apartment numbers dealt with?

Comment: If you want a general solution, utilize a geocoding service and parse the response.  I built such a solution based on the google maps API in the past.  In that situation I was extracting the lat/long values.  I did a quick look and google doesn't break out the house/street number but others may.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this solution. I used `preg_match` to find a Norwegian address like you described in the question:

```
$input_string = 'Mystreet test 33b';

$address = "";
$number = "";

$matches = array();
if(preg_match('/(?P<address>[^\d]+) (?P<number>\d+.?)/', $input_string, $matches)){
    $address = $matches['address'];
    $number = $matches['number'];
} else { // no number found, it is only address
    $address = $input_string;
}

echo "Input: $input_string <br/>";
echo "Address: $address <br />";
echo "Number: $number";
```

Sample output:

```
Input: Mystreet test 33b
Address: Mystreet test
Number: 33b
```

Comment: actually this does not work. Try the input string $input_string = 'heading street 10';

Comment: Works like a charm. But one thing I couldn't get to work:
"Street 38-40" for example. Any Ideas on that?

Answer (score -1):

I don't say this is the perfect solution. But you can consider this.

```
$address="Mystreet 4a";
$code = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "",$address);
if(empty($code))
    echo "No house number found";
else
{
    $houseNumber = strstr($address, $code);
    echo $houseNumber;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way to do that is explode:

```
<?php 
$addr = 'Mystreet 4a';
$parts = explode(' ', $addr);
echo $parts[0]; //this is the street (Mystreet)
echo $parts[1]; //this is the whole number (4a)
echo (int)$parts[1]; // this is the actual number (4)
?>
```

Comment: This won't work for some street names, as they can be made up from multiple words. If you want this approach it would be better to get the number via $parts[count($parts)-1]; (And even then this approach  could be tricky.)